# Does anyone know how to sync a SP Online Form library to a PC using One Drive?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, form, sync

I am trying to sync a SharePoint Online (InfoPath) form library to a PC using One Drive.  I can sync my document libraries containing other MS Office documents, but the control in the form library is grayed out.  Is it possible to sync form libraries?  The library does use browser enabled forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a limitation with OneDrive - has no support on downloading Form files.

You can use freeware http://spsync.net/ which can basically sync all type of files and does the job as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue, it might be by default that the sync button is greyed out in form library.

As a workaround, create a document library and move the form files to this document library and sync them.